# DynamoDB code not working inside of Mocha test case?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, mocha.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

Background:
I've created a Dynamo DB table and populated it. I have some code to read an item in a file called readItem.js which works when I run it stand-alone but does NOT work when I run it as a Mocha test case.

Any ideas why the code is not running properly inside of an it() test case?

For standalone, I run the app like this:

```
node readItem.js
```

readItem.js:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "Movies";
var year = 2015;
var title = "The Big New Movie";
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

However, when I run it inside of a Mocha test case, the callback function on docClient.get() call is not being invoke, i.e.:

```
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) { ...// Not being invoked });
```

Here is how I have the code structured as a test case. I invoke the test with:

```
npm run test
```

Where "test" is defined in my package.json as:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --reporter spec --ui bdd test/"
}
```

Test Case code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
let table = "Movies";
let year = 2015;
let title = "The Big New Movie";
let params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    }
};



describe('DynamoDB Tests', function() {

    it("Read Item", function() {

        try {
            docClient.get(params, function (err,data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                } else {
                    console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                }               
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("ERROR:"+ err);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try having your test setup done in a `before()` hook.

Answer (score 0):

I was using older version of mocha:
"mocha": "^3.5.3"

Upgrading fixed it
"mocha": "^6.1.4"